# Optimize Hashing Java

Tags: java, hash

I'm having a big amount of large lists of objects. Each object has a unique id. It looks something like this:

```
List a = {obj1, obj2, obj3}
List b = {obj3, obj4, obj5}
List c = {obj1, obj2, obj3}
// up to 100 million of them
```

Now I'd like to *remove* "List c" since it has the same content as "List a" in order to save memory.

For this purpose I'm simply adding them all to a hashmap and check if the key already exists. The objects are actually references in a large network graph. If only one is wrong the whole application crashs. Because it is very important that there will never be the same key for different objects I don't use the default

```
List.hashCode()
```

function but do this instead:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for ( List list : myList )
    sb.append(list.getId());
return Hashing.sha256().hashString(sb.toString(), Charsets.US_ASCII).toString();
```

This works perfectly fine. Just it is very slow. Is there any way to achieve the same result in less time?

Comment: Did you try with the default hashcode of your list ? java.util.AbstractList compute a hash from each objecft in the list. toString is a slow operation and it is not needed. If the default hashcode of the list is too slow you should have a look at the hashcode of the object in the list.

Comment: I'm not following why you think that `List`s' `hashCode()` implementation does not serve your purpose.

Comment: *Because it is very important that there will never be the same key for different objects*: Why is that so important to you?  Obviously a SHA256 hash will be very slow :)

Comment: Do you mean that lists whose elements differ must be guaranteed to have different hash codes (i.e. you want a perfect hash)?  That cannot be guaranteed at the level of abstraction of your question.  In particular, your existing implementation does not guarantee it.

Comment: In fact, if you are computing `int` hash codes for 100M distinct objects, then you are consuming around 2% of all the available hash codes.  The technique you describe has a reasonably high probability of producing a few hash collisions in that case.

Comment: Afaik there is no perfect Hash. The likelyhood of a collision in the implementation above is very low though. In fact it never happened so far. Using an `int` hash causes collisions regualary because the range is just to small for so many objects. This is why I was using Strings instead. It works but it is just **very** slow.

Comment: Seriously it is a terrible idea to depend on there never being a hash collision, no matter what kind of hashing algorithm you're using.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `HashSet` and the regular `hashcode` and `methods` from `List` to remove duplicates. Their implementations are similar to your idea.

So:

```
Set<List<String>> uniques = 
    new HashSet<>(Arrays.List<String>asList(a, b, c));  // {a, b}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. When I use the default `hashcode` method of `List` I get an `int`. Having 100 million objects the probabilty of a collision is very high since the range of int is only around 4 billion. It is crucial to avoid collisions.

Comment: That's when ``equals`` come into play: if 2 lists end up with the same hashcode, equality is checked.

Comment: Yes! And remember that it is efficient because equals method is only invoked when there is a collision

Comment: The problem is, that out of my 100 million 90% needs will be removed. So the equals method will be called almost all the time. Performance even slows down then.

Comment: Yes but whatever hash function you use, you still want to check equality anyway for those 90% *anyway*. At most 10% of the time will the hash tell you that the list is unique. So you are trying to optimize something that is not your bottleneck. Try it first.